# Retrieving md5 hash value of an online resource

Tags: linux, hash, md5

I am writing a script that attempts to download an online resource only if that resource does not exist locally on a linux machine. For the local resource I can get the hash value by using the command md5sum 
I want to be able to retrieve the md5 hash of an online resource without having to download it first. Are there any command line utilities able to do this?

eg:

```
#> md5sum http: / / some_domain/some_resource_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
curl http://example.com | md5sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -O- <URL> | md5sum
```

might do.